# How to get the character of a specific position from a stream in c++?

Tags: c++, stream

I have a text file which contains these strings

```
adsklfjas;alfkjalkdsjfaldks;sjf
```

How do I get the 10th character? I know the position(10), but how do I position myself to there?

```
int main()
{
    fstream stream("mytext.txt", fstream::in);

    char c;
    // cout << c << endl;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `ifstream::seekg`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
int main()
{
    fstream stream("test.txt", fstream::in);

    char c;
    stream.seekg(10);
    stream.get(c);
    cout << "c " << stream.tellg() << " : " << c << endl;
}
```